How to Create Table from Json Schema in Snowflake?
I have Json Schema provided by vendor. This Schema has 100+ fields with atleast 4 level nested hierarchy. I want to automatically create staging table using this Json Schema in Snowflake ? Is there any straightforward way to do that ? Thanks

Create the table with VARIANT data type for the JSON column. Then extract the required columns from it

There are some open source projects that can take a JSON schema and output table creation. I didn't find one specific for Snowflake, but this one outputs to Redshift - that should have a similar syntax:

https://better.engineering/jsonschema2db/

However, you will need to deal with the fact that some schemas are transformed into multiple tables, and then you will need to find ways of splitting data between them and making the foreign keys work.
An alternative would be to start from sample data and let Snowflake 'INFER_SCHEMA` from it to generate the tables:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/infer_schema

